# Hide sheets in Google Apps Script with onEdit

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to hide and show a sheet based on the value of a cell, but I keep getting an error when I try to execute it.

This is my current script.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var range = e.range;
  var spreadSheet = e.source;
  var sheetName = spreadSheet.getActiveSheet().getName();
  var rulesSheet = getSheetById(1485384953);
  var column = range.getColumn();
  var row = range.getRow();
  var inputValue = e.value;
  
  if(sheetName == "Queues" && column == 12 && row >= 5 && row <= 200)
  {  
    switch(inputValue)
    {
      case "Yes":
        rulesSheet.showSheet();
        break;
      case "No":
        rulesSheet.hideSheet();
        break;
      default:
        rulesSheet.hideSheet();
    }
  }  

}
```

The expectation is that when the cell on the Queue sheet (M column from rows 5 to 200) has a value of "Yes" then it will show the Rules sheet, and when it has a value of "No" then it will hide it.

The error I get when I try to execute it is "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'range')". Can anybody please tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: You execute these functions by editing a sheet and generating the onEdit trigger which populate the parameter.